# Syntax error in custom forms

Tags: django

I am receiving an error in my syntax when creating a custom form. The error is in the last line "self.fields...". Does anyone know the proper syntax?

```
class UpdateStateWithOptionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = State


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(UpdateStateWithOptionsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['relevantoption']forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.all(),required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an assignment sign `=`:

```
self.fields['relevantoption']forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.all(),required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

should be:

```
self.fields['relevantoption'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.all(),required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Comment: That's it! it looks like I can also add a '.' rather than '=' as well. Both wont' raise an error.

Comment: But only one of them will assign a value!